# MVVMLight Messenger cannot send a null message

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVMLight in Silverlight 5.
Does anyone know why it cannot send a null message?

I am using Send(TMessage message)

Messenger.Default.Send(null);

Generally, if viewmodels need to talk to each other, isn't this one way to do it?
It looks weird that I cannot send a null message.
In my case, I have a Map object which viewmodels need to share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVVM Light V4 beta, a regression bug was introduced that causes null messages to fail with a NullReferenceException. This bug will be fixed ASAP.

Cheers,
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the particular library in question, but if you're calling a method with a generic parameter, you cannot simply pass null because null means "nothing" and it needs a particular kind of nothing.  So for a method like void `Send<TMessage>(TMessage messgae)`, you would have to do something like:

```
Send<string>(null);
```

or

```
Send((string)null);
```

If you subsequently get runtime exceptions (e.g. NullArgumentException), then you could think about defining a NoMessage type with some kind of default/nothing behavior that you want to encapsulate (see [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)).